# Seleccionar las columnas de un csv (sin librerias)

Tags: python, lista, csv, data

El objetivo es crear una lista cuyos elementos sean las listas columnas de un .csv, lo he conseguido hacer para un numero de columnas especifico, lo que no he conseguido hacer es que funcione para un archivo con n columnas y n filas desconocidas.
Debe realizarse sin ultizar librerias como Pandas o Numpy

el csv de ejemplo es:

1,4.0,?,?,none,?

2,2.0,3.0,?,none,38

2,2.5,2.5,?,tc,39

```
import csv 
import sys
lista=[]

with open('libro.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    lista = list(reader)

    #CREAMOS UNA LISTA CUYOS ELEMENTOS SEAN LAS COLUMNAS DEL CSV        
    columna1=[]
    columna2=[]
    columna3=[]
    columna4=[]
    columna5=[]
    columna6=[]
    columnas=[columna1,columna2,columna3,columna4,columna5,columna6]

    for fila in lista:
        for index, elemento in enumerate(fila):
            if index == 0:
                columna1.append(fila[index])
            elif index == 1:
                columna2.append(fila[index])        
            elif index == 2:
                columna3.append(fila[index])
            elif index == 3:
                columna4.append(fila[index])       
            elif index == 4:
                columna5.append(fila[index])
            elif index == 5:
                columna6.append(fila[index])       

    print(columnas)
```

el código imprime:

[['1', '2', '2'], ['4.0', '2.0', '2.5'], ['?', '3.0', '2.5'], ['?', '?', '?'], ['none', 'none', 'tc'], ['?', '38', '39']]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nota: Entiendo que quieres leer el archivo para obtener este resultado:

```
[['1', '2', '2'], ['4.0', '2.0', '2.5'], ['?', '3.0', '2.5'], ['?', '?', '?'], ['none', 'none', 'tc'], ['?', '38', '39']]
```

También se supone que todas las filas traen el mismo número de columnas.

**Solución**

```
import csv
import sys

with open('libro.csv') as data:
    columnas = []
    for fila in csv.reader(data):
        for index, elemento in enumerate(fila):
            if len(columnas) <= index:
                columnas.append([])
            columnas[index].append(elemento)
    print(columnas)
```

produce

```
[['1', '2', '2'], ['4.0', '2.0', '2.5'], ['?', '3.0', '2.5'], ['?', '?', '?'], ['none', 'none', 'tc'], ['?', '38', '39']]
```

La variable `columnas` es una lista. Cada elemento es el contenido de una columna.

Este código lee línea por línea el CSV. Cada línea es separada en N valores, uno por columna usando `enumerate`. Inmediatamente recorremos ese resultado, traspasando el valor i-esimo a `columnas[i-esimo]`.

Si es una columna nueva, que no existe, agregamos una columna vacia. Como el recorrido se hace en orden creciente, no existe el riesgo de encontrar saltos en la numeración.

**Observación**

Si alguna vez te encuentras escribiendo variable1, variable2, variable3, ... variableN, es signo de que debes usar una lista o un arreglo (depende del lenguaje).

Comment: justo, si lo sé pero no lo conseguía automatizar muchas gracias.... pregunta: funciona igual si pones solo reader en vez de list(reader)? cual es la funcion de list() en este caso?

Comment: @zodiak. Correcto. Edite la respuesta para incluir tu observación. La función `list()` transforma una secuencia, collección o iterador en una lista. En este caso, como dedujistes, es redundante.